# saving rotatable graph in r function scatter3d

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot

I have been using the r function scatter3d() to create graphs and can save them as snapshots for publishing purposes but was wondering if there is a way to save the interactive graph for presentation purposes.

thanks

Comment: Is it possible to save the data and reload it in another program such as matlab or mathematica?  There are toolkits in both that are designed for interactive 3d visualizations.

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/jcgs.2010.191ed (paywalled) gives a link to some discussion of how rgl graphics can be embedded in PDF documents (although of course only viewed with sufficiently recent versions of Acrobat): see this thread too: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Exporting-an-rgl-graph-td1872712.html

Comment: thanks that was quite helpful